# get JNDI full url to access a remote whebsphere resource

Tags: websphere, jndi

i've access to the websphere administration console.

What i'm looking for is the url and port to access via jndi to a resource in a java application (the protocoll as well)

in my java code:

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://<server ip address or name>:<server bootstrap address port>");   //<--how can get this url?
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

Answer (score 0):

the ip address / hostname will be the same as where the admin console is hosted.

The bootstrap address is normally 2809 for single-server or 9809 for an ND install

Comment: and  the protocoll is "iiop://"?  whatever url i use the InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env); doesn't throw any exception

Comment: `new InitialContext()` will almost never throw an exception -- you'd see the exception once you try to use the initial context to perform a lookup